# Python permutations

Tags: python

I am trying to generate pandigital numbers using the itertools.permutations function, but whenever I do it generates them as a list of separate digits, which is not what I want.

For example:

```
for x in itertools.permutations("1234"):
    print(x)
```

will produce:

```
('1', '2', '3', '4')
('1', '2', '4', '3')
('1', '3', '2', '4')
('1', '3', '4', '2')
('1', '4', '2', '3')
('1', '4', '3', '2'), etc.
```

whereas I want it to return 1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, etc. How would I go about doing this in an optimal fashion?

Comment: Have you tried just `''.join(x)` them back?

Comment: umm..concatenate the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list comprehension with the built-in `str.join()` function is what you need:

```
import itertools
a = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations("1234") ]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['1234', '1243', '1324', '1342', '1423', '1432', '2134', '2143', '2314', '2341', '2413', '2431', '3124', '3142', '3214', '3241', '3412', '3421', '4123', '4132', '4213', '4231', '4312', '4321']
```

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.permutations` takes an iterable and returns an iterator yielding tuples.

Use `join()` that return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable iterable

`join()` [DOCS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), 
`itertools.permutations` [DOCS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Use this:

```
import itertools

for x in itertools.permutations("1234"):
    print (''.join(x))
```

**Output:**

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
....
```

Answer (score 2):

see [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) return tuple. 
see join function:

```
In [1]: ''.join(('1','2','3'))
Out[1]: '123'
```

try this:

```
for x in itertools.permutations("1234"):
        print ''.join(x)
```